# How to send array of objects using HTML from to Nodejs Express

Tags: html, node.js, express

I have the following HTML form which I use to send array of objects to my Node.js / Express back-end (I'm using Pug),

```
each val in [1, 2]
    div(class = "row")
        div(class= "col")
            select(class="form-select" name = "items[][service]")
                each service in services
                    option(value=service._id) #{service.name}                
        div(class= "col")
            input(type="text" name="items[][description]" class='form-control mb-4' placeholder="Description")
        div(class= "col")
            input(type="text" name="items[][amount]" class='form-control mb-4' placeholder="QTY")
        div(class= "col")
            input(type="text" name="items[][price]" class='form-control mb-4' placeholder="Price")
        div(class= "col")
            input(type="text" name="items[][subtotal]" class='form-control mb-4' placeholder="Subtotal")
```

And this is my app.js file (using body parser)

```
const app = Express();
app.use(cookieParser());
app.set("view engine", "pug");
app.use(json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use("/admin", adminRouter);
set("strictQuery", false);
set("autoCreate", false);
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8000);
```

And this is my `req.body` log

```
 items: [
    {
      service: [Array],
      description: [Array],
      amount: [Array],
      price: [Array],
      subtotal: [Array]
    }
  ],
```

I even tried to hard code the array index like `items[0].service`, but all my attempts fails, what is the appropriate way to send this kind of data to Node.js?

Comment: try log(req.body.items.services)
Data comes, bodyparser parses, everything ok but conole.log, concentrates  you to see structure of this large set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `index` variable in iteration, and then use that index to designate element in the array, according to the structure you want:

```
each val, index in [1, 2]
```

and then:

```
...
input(type="text" name="items["+index+"][description]" 
input(type="text" name="items["+index+"][amount]" class='form-control 
...
```

Note:  if you also have a nested array, you would add index there the same way

the code:

```
each val, index in [1, 2]
                div(class = "row")
                    div(class= "col")
                        select(class="form-select" name = "items["+index+"][service]")
                            each service in services
                                option(value=service._id) #{service.name}                
                    div(class= "col")
                        input(type="text" name="items["+index+"][description]" class='form-control mb-4' placeholder="Description")
                    div(class= "col")
                        input(type="text" name="items["+index+"][amount]" class='form-control mb-4' placeholder="QTY")
                    div(class= "col")
                        input(type="text" name="items["+index+"][price]" class='form-control mb-4' placeholder="Price")
                    div(class= "col")
                        input(type="text" name="items["+index+"][subtotal]" class='form-control mb-4' placeholder="Subtotal")
```

Comment: Thanks man now its working, but i'm sure i hardcoded the index before and it didn't work!

Comment: it might work hardcoded, but instead of `items[0].service` use brackets: `items[0][service]`

Comment: yes, this is why it didn't work for me, thanks again man